# Records doubled on sql query left join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables and I am using join to get common records from those 2 tables.

I have used the following query but my problem is I am getting the records doubled.

The query is as follows, can you help me ?

**Query #1 :** ( correct output )

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT
    xId1 AS xId1,
    xArea AS xArea,
    YEAR (
        STR_TO_DATE(
            `xDate`,
            '%d/%m/%Y'
        )
    ) AS xYear
FROM
    doTable1 AA
LEFT JOIN doTable2 BB ON AA.xId1 = BB.xId2
WHERE
    xArea IN ('XX1A')
AND YEAR (
    STR_TO_DATE(
        `xDate`,
        '%d/%m/%Y'
    )
) = 2016;

+-----------+-------+-------+
| xId       | xArea | xYear |
+-----------+-------+-------+
| 91623545  | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 89748942  | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 115956872 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 103595808 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 103623873 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 103623892 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 103623872 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 103623894 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 112072738 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 112072751 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 117818773 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 117818753 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 117885105 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 117960040 | XX1A  |  2016 |
| 117885111 | XX1A  |  2016 |
+-----------+-------+-------+

15 rows in set
```

**Query #2 :** ( incorrect output because for 2016 year I have 18 records - doubled presence - and not 15 records as on **Query #1**):

```
mysql> SELECT 
    DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS xQQQ,
    xArea AS xArea,
    YEAR (
        STR_TO_DATE(
            xDate,
            '%d/%m/%Y'
        )
    ) AS xYear
FROM
    doTable1 AA
LEFT JOIN doTable2 BB ON AA.xId1 = BB.xId2
WHERE xArea IN ('XX1A')
GROUP BY
    xArea,
    xYear;
+------+-------+-------+
| xQQQ | xArea | xYear |
+------+-------+-------+
|    4 | XX1A  |  2014 |
|   49 | XX1A  |  2015 |
|   18 | XX1A  |  2016 |
+------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set
```

Comment: In these cases I replace the SELECT with SELECT * and run the query without GROUP BY, and look at each line for itself. It is almost impossible to guess what the problem is without having the complete database.

Comment: @Linkan thank yuo for help, but I have posted the **Query #1** without **GROUP BY**

Comment: That str_to_date bit seems a little redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your SQL. if you want distinct counts, have to use like this

```
COUNT(DISTINCT xId1 )
```

Please run and see.

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT xId1 ) AS xQQQ,
        xArea AS xArea,
        YEAR (
            STR_TO_DATE(
                `DATA PUBBLICAZIONE`,
                '%d/%m/%Y'
            )
        ) AS xYear
    FROM
        doTable1 AA
    LEFT JOIN doTable2 BB ON AA.xId1 = BB.xId2
    WHERE xArea IN ('XX1A')
    GROUP BY
        xArea,
        xYear;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!